# Enable AVPlayerViewController customInfoViewController interaction tvOS

Tags: swift, uikit, tvos, avkit

I am creating a player app for tvOS. I am trying to add a button to restart the playback (I can not use the Markers). The Apple Human Interface Guidelines [states](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/system-capabilities/video-player/):

> The built-in video player includes an info panel that displays information about the video and lets viewers change settings for items such as subtitles, spoken languages, or speaker output. By default, the info panel contains three tabs titled Info, Subtitles, and Audio. (The TV app uses Chapters in place of Info.) **You can provide a fourth tab if people need to access content-specific information or settings that you support**.

"Settings that you support" means that the user can interact with the settings, I suppose. The problem is that I can not manage to enable user interaction. If I add a button in the controller, the user can not focus it, so it turns out to be useless.

Does anyone know how to be able to select a button in there? I couldn't find anything on the web.

Comment: Hello! Have you found a workaround with fourth tab in tvOS info panel?

Comment: Hi there Pete, unfortunately no. I think it that controller is not intended to be interactive at this point. Hope it will be one day.

Answer (score 0):

This currently works for allowing the button to be focused

```
 let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
 button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
 button.setTitle("Focused", for: .focused)
        
 customInfoPanel.view = button
        
 playerController.customInfoViewController = customInfoPanel
```